# Existe uma forma de descriptografar MD5 em php?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, md5

existe alguma forma de descriptografar **md5** em **php** ?

preciso descriptografar o valor que vem de um **cookie** para pegar informações do usuário

Comment: Essa é uma operação legal?

Comment: MD5 não é possível descriptografar, o que existe são alguns dicionários de possíveis valores. Mas o processo é irreversível teoricamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois que um dado é criptografado em md5 você só pode compara-lo, por exemplo um sistema de login, quando você cria sua conta sua senha é criptografada e salva no banco de dados, quando vc tenta se logar a senha que você digita no campo senha é criptografada novamente e o resultado é comparado com o que tem no banco de dados se o resultado for true a senha está correta e você pode se logar.

Dependendo do uso existem alguns dicionários online, onde eles mostram como determinada sequencia de caracteres fica em md5 mais não é algo recomendado, se realmente quer uma solução pro seu problema seria interessante falar oque tem em mente para podermos ajudar :D

Answer (score 4):

Jefferson MD5 é um algoritmo de hash unidirecional e, portanto, uma vez criptografados, os dados não podem mais ser descriptografados.

Answer (score 1):

Jefferson como os Alexandre e o Edilson já falaram, não é recomendado, e acredito que nem seja possível descriptografar um hash gerado via md5.

Mas tenho uma sugestão para você, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php, o mcrypt é uma função de PHP que faz a criptografia e possuí o par dela que descriptografa(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php).

Acho que faça mais sentido para você utilizar uma ferramenta para criptografia no lugar de uma de hash.

Abs,